# How to get the cell element that is spanning another cell element in a table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

We have a table:

```html
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Column 1</td>
                <td colspan="3">Column 2</td>
                <td>Column 3</td>
                <td colspan="99999">Column 4</td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>B</td>
                <td id="target">C</td>
                <td>D</td>
                <td>E</td>
                <td>F</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Using JavaScript or jQuery, how would we able to get the column element (or its index) of the first row that is spanning the cell with id "target"?  I don't really want to use any box positioning method (is: getBoundingClientRect()) technique.

In this example, the associated cell element that is spanning "target" is the cell with text "Column 2".

Comment: Get the index of the target (2), loop through the "header" row (would be better if it was in a thead and used th... but nevermind...) - add up rowspans (count as 1 if no rowspan, obvs) if the count>= your target index, that's your column

Comment: It seems that there isn't any built-in API for getting the computed position of a cell within a table (see [HTMLTableCellElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement) on MDN). If your table only contains colspans and not rowspans, you can compute the position of a cell by just looping through the cells in the row up to it and checking the colspans. But if the table contains rowspans then the computation would be a lot more complicated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... what are you building? Why do you need this exactly? So far it seems like you tried nothing (read: [ask]) - and this seems so far like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#:~:text=An%20XY%20problem%20seems%20to,everyone%2C%20novices%20and%20experts%20alike.)

Comment: I am making table columns toggle (show/hide) and each column header belongs under a certain top header column that may or may not span column(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for the case, that the second row also has colspans and there is no third row:

---

Iterate over the cells of the second row with a for loop and count their colspans until you find your target cell (if there is no colspan defined it is automatically `'1'`). Then iterate over the cells of the first row and count their colspans until the count is equal or bigger then the count of the second row. In that case you have found the desired head cell.

**Working example:**

```js
const head_cells = document.querySelectorAll('#head-row td');
const target_cells = document.querySelectorAll('#target-row td');
let head_position = 0;
let target_position = 0;

for (i = 0; i < target_cells.length; i++) {
  target_position += target_cells[i].colSpan;

  if (target_cells[i].id === 'target') {
    for (k = 0; k < head_cells.length; k++) {
      head_position += head_cells[k].colSpan;

      if (head_position >= target_position) {
        console.log(head_cells[k].textContent);
        break;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="head-row">
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td colspan="4">Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
      <td colspan="99999">Column 4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="target-row">
      <td>A</td>
      <td colspan="2">B</td>
      <td id="target">C</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why hardcoding magic numbers like in `'tr:nth-child(2) td'` ?

Comment: changed it to last-child...

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily and exactly  *"a last child"*. Might be any N-child, no? Cannot we do it dynamically instead of hardcoding strict N childness?

Comment: solved now with IDs...

Comment: Seems to work with any cell configuration.  Very nice.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script>
function findHeader(cell) {
    let count = cell.cellIndex + 1; // 3
    for(let header of headers.cells) {
        const colspan = +header.getAttribute('colspan') || 1;
        count -= colspan;
        if (count<1) return alert(header.textContent);
    }
}
</script>
<table border=1>
<tbody>
    <tr id="headers">
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td colspan="3">Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td colspan="99999">Column 4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td onclick="findHeader(this)">Click</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Just noting that this code assumes there are no colspans in the data row, and no rowspans in the entire table.